# Using a plugin into the header

Tags: jekyll, octopress

Is it possible to use a plugin into the header ?
For example, display one image after the title, in header.html.

```
<hgroup>
   <h1><a href="{{ root_url }}/">{{ site.title }}</a></h1>
   {% if site.subtitle %}
      <h2>{{ site.subtitle }}</h2>
   {% endif %}
   {% img /images/my_image.jpg %}
</hgroup>
```

Note that I didn't try ...

Answer (score 0):

The image isn't really a plugin, but you should be able to add an image. I would use an `img` tag instead, so `<img src="/images/my_image.jpg">` instead, but that may work as well.

You can also use `{% include file_path %}` If you want to include your own widgets. Please note that file_path is the file path in `source/_include/...`